# Calculate Standard Deviation using Java?

Tags: java, math, arraylist, standard-deviation

I have an ArrayList of integers: [11, 15, 10, 19, 9, 1, 2, 16]
  and I can't seem to return the right answer.

My code:

```
static double Q2(ArrayList<Integer> input) {
    Collections.sort(input);

    ArrayList<Double> input2 = new ArrayList<>();
    double sum = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double sd = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + input.get(i);
    }

    double mean = sum / input.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        input2.add((Math.pow((input.get(i) - mean), 2)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input2.size(); i++) {
        sum2 = sum2 + input2.get(i);
    }

    double mean2 = sum2 / input2.size();

    sd = Math.sqrt(mean2);

    return sd;
```

The Expected output should be: 5.998697775350913

My output is : 6.010407640085654

Thank you for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: I got the correct output using your code. http://ideone.com/XmTDb2

Comment: I have simplified your code: http://ideone.com/hWTBgi. Result is 5.998697775350913

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your input, check that is the same list you post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although mathematically correct, this is, computationally, a terrible way to compute SD. There is no need to sort the inputs first. There is no need to create a second array to store the squared deviations; you can just add them as you go in one loop. There is no need to call Math.Pow instead of just computing z * z.

Fix all that, and you will have improved this approach as much as you can. But a better approach entirely is to use an [online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm), which can do it in one pass.

Finally, be aware that in many cases when people ask you to compute the SD, they actually want the population SD, not the sample SD, which requires you to divide the sum of squared deviations by (n-1) instead of n.